# How is this pregmatch working?

Tags: preg-match

I'm looking at some code that has

```
preg_match('/\[youtube ([[:print:]]+)\]/', $content, $matches)
```

`$content` could be a link such as *http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some_video*

I can see it's filtering for youtube video, but I don't get how it's doing it. More specifically, what's the role of `[:print:]`?

Comment: Have you read the [`re_format(7)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format) man page to see how character classes work?

Comment: honestly this is the first I'm learning about character classes. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php#81559

"[:print:] - printing characters, including space"

Comment: That's so simple! I hadn't come across character classes before now. And btw the preg_match isn't even working since it fails to capture valid links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an experiment in box drawing.

```
/\[youtube ([[:print:]]+)\]/
│ │        │ │          │
│ │        │ │          └─ close the matched string
│ │        │ └──────────── start the character class
│ │        └────────────── open the matched string
│ └─────────────────────── literal square bracket
└───────────────────────── start the regexp
```

The important bit is the part inside parentheses.  That gets matched by your programming language for re-use as a variable, so that you can construct your replacement URL.